# Adding product combinations

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm doing a prestashop module and I need to add combinations with sizes

I'm doing this
`$product = new Product($idProduct);

```
    $attribute = new ProductAttribute();
    $attribute->name = $attributeName;
    $attribute->public_name = $attributeName;
    $attribute->add();

    $idAtributoTalla = (int)$attribute->id;

    $attributeValue = new AttributeGroup();
    $attributeValue->id_attribute_group = $idAtributoTalla;
    $attributeValue->name = array_fill(0, Language::getLanguages(false, false), $attributeValue);
    $attributeValue->position = ProductAttribute::getHigherPosition($idAtributoTalla) + 1;
    $attributeValue->add();

    $product->update();

    $product->addProductAttributeCombination($idAtributoTalla, array($idAtributoTalla));

    $product->update();`
```

but when I execute the code I have a error: The ProductAttribute->id_attribute_group property is empty.

I'd tried to add manualy a group id but didn't works

Comment: You instance `ProductAttribute` but never set its ID, I don't know much about Prestashop but unless that automatically sets the `id` property in the constructor or `add` method, it is likely `null` !!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `$attribute->add()` without specifying `id_attribute_group` property. This is a required property, and you can not add a new ProductAttribute without this.

The ProductAttribute object model is mapped to the table `attribute`, which is the "size number" in your scenario (e.g: 37, 38, 39). It must be mapped to a `AttributeGroup` object model.